# Blocking Unwanted Visitors: htaccess, iptables, or just database

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, iptables

We've recently had a client get hammered with bots signing up for accounts as well as looking for directories that don't exists (/phpmyadmin/, /pma/, /members/, /admin/, etc.). We've created a way to scrape through the access logs and identify the malicious IP's, however I'm wondering the most effective solution.

After the initial scrape, I tried adding about 10,000 IP's to iptables to be blocked. This seemed to make things a little slow and I started to wonder what would be best to block the offending bots/malicious users. Using iptables, htaccess, or simply a database. The database approach seems the simplest, but I'd rather not have the malicious users wasting a query if it is more efficient to block them at the htaccess or iptables level.

Is there a method that is preferred for large amounts of addresses? What are the considerations, if any, for each?

This is a simple webserver running a PHP/MySQL application.

Thank you.

Comment: Also on the table I suppose would be hosts.deny

Answer (score 1):

For the mass sign-up part, a simple and effective captcha should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

don't even try stop them, you will block legit traffic,slow your site and they have an infinite number of ip's to come from, just make sure they cant get anywhere they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constantly updating IP address lists (constantly changing) or user agents (easily spoofed), block the specific hacker patterns in all the server variables.
See http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

Answer (score -2):

You could also try blocking by user-agent string (these should show up in your logs)

```
//in htaccess
BrowserMatchNoCase SpammerRobot bad_bot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/block-bots-with-htaccess.shtml

Comment: Most bad bots are going to use a faked user agent that looks like a normal browsing user.

Comment: That makes sense, but it might be worth checking if some of them aren't using fake user agents